# Using root installed programs in standard account

Tags: kali-linux, application

After I installed Kali Linux, I was using it as root and downloaded and installed many applications such as netbeans, xampp and more... But then after I created a normal user. When I log in with this normal user I cannot access my installed programs. What should I do in order to use a program installed as root in a standard account?

Comment: You need to make those application executable: `chmod o+x myprogram`. Also, they need to be in your path (`which myprogram` to check if it is)

Comment: The default action for most software when installed from the `root` account with, for example, `make install`, is to install it in places like `/usr/local` that are available to any user. How and where did you install your software?

Comment: I installed them in their default location.

Comment: Add output from $PATH to your question.(type "echo $PATH" in your terminal)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your PATH variable. You can do that in .bashrc:

```
PATH='/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin'
```

Basically when you run program, $PATH is where it will be searched(path is list of directories separated by : ). If it can't find it there, you get an error message - which is your case.

I added most popular locations, but you might have installed your applications in different directories; in that case, simply change string that I provided accordingly.